# POST-Redirect-GET in ASP.NET Core MVC preserving user input and validation messages

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

I have a multi-page form to submit and update an application for an event built using ASP.NET Core MVC. Each page of the form consists of the display information managed by the organizer (1) and the information entered by the user (2) *(e.g. a list of locations of venues (1) the the choice of venues (2))*.

I want it to use the POST-Redirect-GET pattern. I consider it more user-friendly. (It avoids pop-ups a user might not understand and accidentally overwriting submitted information.) I do not want to keep user input and show the validation errors.

I have a working implementation, but I'm not sure about performance.
I can best explain my approach using (C#) code:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Step1(int id)
    {
        this.TempData.TryGetValue("viewModel", out Object? viewModelJSON);
        Step1ViewModel viewModel;
        if (viewModelJSON == null)
        {
           // create empty view model
           viewModel = new Step1ViewModel();
           viewModel.ID = id;
           // when simple GET: show data from db
           var userInputModel = await this.LoadVenueChoicesAsync(id);
           // fill view model if data exists
           if (userInputModel != null) {
              viewModel.UserInput = BuildUserInputViewModel(userInputModel);
           }
        }
        else
        {
            // when GET after POST: show input
            viewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Step1ViewModel>(viewModelJSON);
            await this.TryValidateModelAsync(viewModel);
        }
        var venueList = await this.LoadVenuesAsync();
        viewModel.Information = BuildInformationViewModel(venueList);

        return this.View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Step1(Step1ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var viewModelJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Step1ViewModel>(viewModel);
            this.TempData["viewModel"] = viewModelJSON;
            return this.RedirectToAction("Step1", new { id = viewModel.ID });
        }
        else
        {
            await this.StoreVenueChoicesAsync(viewModel.UserInput);
            return this.RedirectToAction("Step2", new { id = viewModel.ID });
        }
    }
}
```

The web form is going to be used for a short time by many users, so performance must be good. Because of that I would like to validate this approach. Some specific questions I have:

- Will the serialization to JSON be a performance issue? Should I use something else?
- The [learn.microsoft.com page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata) states that `Session` should be used with `LoadAsync()` method to avoid performance issues. Because `TempData` uses `Session`, I wonder whether I should call this method as well?
- Are there other issues with this approach?

(This question was first [asked on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/74208829))

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Could you please share us the definition of the `Step1ViewModel` to be able to answer your first question?

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw In my previous edit, I renamed two variable names to be more descriptive and I added an example ViewModel. Both changes are made only to improve understanding for reviewers (and other readers). The ViewModel was even explicitly asked for another moderator. I did not change anything significant and I did not change anything `BCdotWeb` mentioned. The changes have nothing to do with the questions I asked. ...

Comment: ... If you want me to post a new review request or post these additions as an answer, tell me so. I think that would be less helpful/clear both for me, for others, and it would be less appreciative to `BCdotWeb`'s effort.

Comment: It wasn't clear what to do, so I posted an updated question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/281092/266308

Answer (score 2):

**Some quick remarks:**

- Names need to be meaningful: `TempData` isn't.
- `this.TempData.TryGetValue("viewModel",` and `this.TempData["viewModel"] =`: now image you rename `"viewModel"` but forget to do it everywhere. Constants like that should be `const string`, preferably stored in a separate, clearly named class.
- Comments should only be used to clarify code that isn't self-explanatory. `// create empty view model` is pointless, and the same goes for most of your comments.
- Methods should be properly named. I don't expect a method named `LoadVenueChoicesAsync` to return anything, whereas I expect a method that starts with `Get` to return something. Same for `BuildUserInputViewModel`.
- Don't pollute your methods with the word "Async" unless you have two methods and one is the sync version and the other the async.
- Follow the capitalization rules: `viewModelJSON` doesn't follow them. `JSON` is longer than two letters and thus should be written `Json`. Any abbreviation over two letters should be PascalCased or camelCased (depending on context.
- `Step1ViewModel` is still a fairly short name, but consider reducing the name of ViewModels by shortening it to "VM" at the end.
- Why do you use multiple lines when one would suffice?

  ```
        var viewModelJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Step1ViewModel>(viewModel);
        this.TempData["viewModel"] = viewModelJSON;
  ```

  There is no need to assign `viewModelJSON`. Just do it in one line.
- Don't call something "xxxList", e.g. `venueList`. Use the proper plural, in this case `venues`.
- Why is there a `this` in front of `this.TempData` and `this.LoadVenuesAsync()` etc.?
- These two methods alone are 40+ lines, and we're only at step 1. Consider moving the bulk of the contents of those methods to their own class (e.g. "Step1Handler") to keep your controller lean.

  Presumably all those methods you call are in that controller as well? I presume this controller is hundreds of lines long? Please rethink this approach: preferably methods and classes should be fairly short.

Comment: I feel like these remarks are mostly things that depend on familiarity with the code style.

Comment: I did extract a constant for the TempData key.