# POST-Redirect-GET in ASP.NET Core MVC preserving user input and validation messages (v2)

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

I have a multi-page form to submit and update an application for an event built using ASP.NET Core MVC. Each page of the form consists of the display information managed by the organizer (1) and the information entered by the user (2) *(e.g. a list of locations of venues (1) the the choice of venues (2))*.

I want it to use the POST-Redirect-GET pattern. I consider it more user-friendly. (It avoids pop-ups a user might not understand and accidentally overwriting submitted information.) I do want to keep user input and show the validation errors after redirect.

I have a working implementation, but I'm not sure about performance.

I can best explain my approach using (C#) code*:

```cs
// /Controller/ApplicationController.cs

using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.ViewModels.Application;

namespace MyApp.Controllers;

public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Step1(int id)
    {
        this.TempData.TryGetValue("viewModel", out Object? viewModelJSON);

        Step1ViewModel viewModel;
        if (viewModelJSON == null)
        {
           // create empty view model
           viewModel = new Step1ViewModel();
           viewModel.ApplicationID = id;
           // when simple GET: show data from db
           var venueChoiceList = await this.LoadVenueChoicesAsync(id);
           // fill view model if data exists
           if (venueChoiceList != null) {
              viewModel.UserInput = BuildUserInputViewModel(venueChoiceList);
           }
        }
        else
        {
            // when GET after POST: show input
            viewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Step1ViewModel>(viewModelJSON);
            await this.TryValidateModelAsync(viewModel);
        }
        var venueList = await this.LoadVenuesAsync();
        viewModel.Information = BuildInformationViewModel(venueList);

        return this.View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Step1(Step1ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var viewModelJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Step1ViewModel>(viewModel);
            this.TempData["viewModel"] = viewModelJSON;
            return this.RedirectToAction("Step1", new { id = viewModel.ApplicationID });
        }
        else
        {
            await this.StoreVenueChoicesAsync(viewModel.UserInput);
            return this.RedirectToAction("Step2", new { id = viewModel.ApplicationID });
        }
    }
}

// /ViewModels/Application/Step1ViewModel.cs
namespace MyApp.ViewModels.Application;

public class Step1ViewModel
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public UserInputViewModel UserInput { get; set; }
    public InformationViewModel Information { get; set; } 

    public class UserInputViewModel
    {
        public List<VenueChoiceViewModel> VenueChoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class VenueChoiceViewModel
    {
        public int VenueID { get; set; }
        public bool Attends { get; set; } 
    }

    public class InformationViewModel
    {
        public List<VenueViewModel> Venues { get; set; }
    }

    public class VenueViewModel 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // ... some more information about the venue
    }
}
```

<sub>*This code represents the general flow of building and submitting the model. In most action handlers there is some extra specific logic.</sub>

The web form is going to be used for a short time by many users, so performance must be good. Because of that I would like to validate this approach. Some specific questions I have:

- Will the serialization to JSON be a performance issue? Should I use something else?
- The [learn.microsoft.com page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata) states that `Session` should be used with `LoadAsync()` method to avoid performance issues. Because `TempData` uses `Session`, I wonder whether I should call this method as well?
- Are there other issues with this approach?

(1) (This question was first [asked on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/74208829))

(2) ([I asked this previously on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280773/post-redirect-get-in-asp-net-core-mvc-preserving-user-input-and-validation-messa)). I got requests for clarification. I did clarify the code (I did not process any tips for improvement), but the changes were undone. When I asked what to do instead, I got no answer. I don't like to spam this question again, but it might be what the  moderator wants. I think it might be important to get this right.)